# What is wrong with this JQuery event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

Sorry, that I have been posting here so often -- I have been doing a lot of work and in turn have ran into lots of problems.

The click handler just modifies some global variables and sends those variables off to update the page via Ajax. Here is my Javascript: (please note that the getPosts function is working, but it is not being called on .click() presumably).

if you wish to view the documents in the flesh, go to www.ethoma.com/testhome.php and for the php go to www.ethoma.com/getposts.php.

```
var category = "undefined";
var page = 0;
var order="id";

function getPosts(){
            var queryString = "category=" + category + "&page=" + page + "&order=" + order;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getposts.php',
                data: queryString,
                success: function(data) {
                $('#postcontainer').html(data);
                 }
            });
        }
$(document).ready(function() {
            getPosts();
         });

         setTimeout(getPosts(), 20000);

         $("#all").click(function(){
                category = "etc.";
                getPosts(); 
            });
```

Comment: i assume that somewhere on the page is an element with id="all"?  also, shouldn't the click handler be in the $(document).ready() function?

Comment: Hi Eric - don't worry about asking lots of questions, it's what the site is for. But, if someone provides a solution, you should mark the answer as accepted (by clicking the big tick next to the answer). You currently have asked four questions and accepted none of the answers.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even realize that it was there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your click is assigned outside the document.ready

I would do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  getPosts();
  setTimeout(getPosts, 20000); // notice I removed the ()

  $("#all").click(function(){
    category = "etc.";
    getPosts(); 
  });

});
```

Firefox console even tells you one of the errors, except in a very w3schools way ;)

> Error: useless setTimeout call (missing quotes around argument?)
>   Source File: http://www.ethoma.com/testhome.php Line: 39

Answer (score 3):

Your click event is outside of `$(document).ready`, so if the javascript runs before the element `#all` is loaded, the click won't be attached. It's good practice to wrap all of your code inside the ready event

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var category = "undefined";
    var page = 0;
    var order = "id";

    function getPosts() {
        var queryString = "category=" + category + "&page=" + page + "&order=" + order;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getposts.php',
            data: queryString,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#postcontainer').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    getPosts();

    setTimeout(getPosts(), 20000);

    $("#all").click(function() {
        category = "etc.";
        getPosts();
    });
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the `live` function to bind the event to all matching elements *whether they appear now or later in the execution process*. Just change `$("#all").click(function` to `$("#all").live('click', function`

Comment: you missed the (getPosts(),20000)

Comment: Seen it thanks, and I had missed it. I was focusing on why the click wasn't binding.

Answer (score 2):

Put this piece of code:

```
    $("#all").click(function(){
            category = "etc.";
            getPosts(); 
        });
```

inside the `$(document).ready` function so that you install the click handler after the page has loaded and the object #all is present.

You will also have fix the call to `setTimeout` as mplungjan mentions.

As for programming style, it's bad form to pass parameters to `getPosts()` in global variables.  Why not just pass the category name to the `getPosts("etc.")` function directly and avoid the global category variable entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Put this:

```
 $("#all").click(function(){
            category = "etc.";
            getPosts(); 
        });
```

...inside your document ready function. Also, you don't want to invoke getPosts in the call to set timeout, just pass `getPosts` (no parentheses).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

        getPosts();


        setTimeout(function(){getPosts();}, 20000);

        $("#all").click(function(){
              category = "etc.";
              getPosts(); 
        });
});
```

put it into document.ready event :)